# GNUPlot 3D Intensity Map for Partial DiffEQ Solution

Tags: graph, gnuplot, pde

I am creating a program that solves a 3D partial differential equation using finite difference methods. This is surprisingly not the hard part, and it is technically finished.

At the end of the program, I am writing the numerical solutions to the PDE in the following format to some file (for later processing)

```
X Y Z C
0 0 0 0.1
0 0 1 etc etc
```

Where X Y and Z are spatial coordinates and C is the intensity at each location.

I found one a lot of information on plotting 3D data with 2 spatial dimensions and 1 intensity. So "technically" I have 4D data ... 3 spacial, 1 intensity.

The one piece of information I found was using this command:
      splot 'datafile' u 1:2:3:4 w pm3d

Which does do the job, but since it is a rectangular prism, you can't easily see the concentration at the center of the prism.

I was imagining that the best way to do this would be to take a "chunk" out of the rectangular prism, so that you can see the intensity layers. The best analogy I could think of was the how text books represent the layers of the earth, where they take a chunk of the earth out to show all the way down to the core.

Another way I saw in research papers was to plot and XY cross section, YZ cross section and XZ cross section all on the same graph.

I have tried to search for both of these but it is very hard (for me) to concisely articulate.

Any advice would be great on the best way to represent this data!

Answer (score 0):

I always find color maps to be the most helpful when interpreting data. You basically plot slices though planes with sensible information. If you have gridded data this is very easy to do in gnuplot even without preprocessing the data file. For instance, if your data looks like this:

```
# x  y  z  c
  0  0  0  0.15
  1  0  0  0.14
  2  0  0  0.16

  0  1  0  0.11
  1  1  0  0.19
  2  1  0  0.12

  0  2  0  0.15
  1  2  0  0.19
  2  2  0  0.13

  0  0  1  0.10
  1  0  1  0.09
  2  0  1  0.17

# etc
```

then you can make a conditional plot with gnuplot for a fixed value of x, y or z. For the z = 0 plane, this could be achieved with `splot "data" u 1:2:($3 == 0 ? $4 : 1/0)`, that is, if 3rd column's value is 0 then plot the 4th column's value, else ignore that point. For the simple example above:

```
set pm3d map
splot "data" u 1:2:($3 == 0 ? $4 : 1/0)
```

[image]

Note that `pm3d` does some interpolation between data points.

If you preprocess your data or have it nicely structured like in my example, you can also use the `with image style`, that might be preferred over `pm3d` for several reasons, including smaller file sizes:

```
plot "data" u 1:2:4 every :::0::2 with image
```

[image]

Where there is no interpolation but the actual point values. `every :::0::2` above selected data blocks 0 to 2, which are the ones that belong to z = 0 in my example.

Finally, if your data is non gridded, you cannot use `with image` and should use `pm3d` instead. In this case the command should take into considerations points that are at an acceptable distance from the plane where you want to plot. This could be achieved as follows:

```
set pm3d map
plane_z = 0
splot "data" u 1:2:( abs($3 - plane_z) < 0.1 ? $4 : 1/0)
```

Above I include in the plot all the points whose z values are less than a distance 0.1 away from the plane (z = 0) I'm interested in.